# How string to {Integer[] image} in android.

Tags: java, android

```
public Integer[] imgs = new Integer[]{ 
R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher

};

String s_img = "R.drawable.img_test";
```

i want

- imgs[0] = s_img
- imgs[0] == R.drawable.img_test
- true !!

What shall I do?

Comment: I didn't really get what you're trying to achieve. Can you rephrase?

Comment: properly elaborate question

Comment: you want to match the values of array with the resource of image? @jin Hyun Hwang

Comment: don't use a String, that will be a pain to make the comparison (you'll have to use getResources().getIdentifier, split the string to find the type and the actual id, then get the int value of it, then compare. Very painful to do.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
s_img = "img_test";//not "R.drawable.img_test" just the name of the image
if(getResources().getIdentifier(s_img, "drawable", getPackageName()) == imgs[0]){
   return true;
}else{
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an array of drawables, right?

```
Integer[] drawables = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, ....};
```

And you can access values by:

`drawables[0]` == R.drawable.image1

`drawables[1]` == R.drawable.image2

And you loop them aswel.

Answer (score 0):

for comparing Object do not use  "**==**"

try

```
"R.drawable.img_test".equals(Integer.toString(imgs[0]));
```

Comment: `Integer.toString(imgs[0])` returns something like "45678123", not the name of the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure of the value R.drawable.ic_launcher, I thought he is trying to compare Strings

Comment: Integer.toString returns a String representation of an int. It means it will always return something that looks like "123456789". And it will certainly never return something that looks like "R.drawable.img_test"

Comment: yes You are correct, the above condition will never be true

Answer (score 0):

Put them in an Enum instead of array.

Answer (score 0):

tell me is that exactly what you need or not ,i think i git what you need .

```
public Integer[] imgs = new Integer[]{ 
    R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher
                 };


    String s_img;

     s_img = Integer.toString(x);
```